# Navbar's fixed position is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been searching for hours and simply cannot find an answer on why my navbar will not stay at the top with position fixed
here is my code: http://pastebin.com/eZnBuAEe
I am using animate.css and wow.js

```js
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    new WOW().init();
    </script>
    
    
    
    <script>
    
    
  $(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
    
    </script>
    
    
    
    
    
  <script>
 ( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#cssmenu').prepend('<div id="menu-button">Menu</div>');
    $('#cssmenu #menu-button').on('click', function(){
     var menu = $(this).next('ul');
     if (menu.hasClass('open')) {
      menu.removeClass('open');
     }
     else {
      menu.addClass('open');
     }
    });
});
} )( jQuery );

 </script>
```

```css
#navBar {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
#nav {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 5px black;
    z-index: 3;
    position: fixed;
    
    width: 100%;
    
}
#cssmenu {
    position: fixed;
     margin-top: 0;
  height: 60px;
  background: #203F4F;
  margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
#cssmenu #main {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
   margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;   
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu ul:after,
#cssmenu:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: auto;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li {
  max-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  background: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #000000;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 13px;
  right: 15px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul li ul li.has-sub:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 15px;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;

}
#cssmenu.align-right ul li ul li.has-sub:before {
  right: auto;
  left: 15px;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu #media{
    margin-right: 15%;
    font: 40px;
 float: right;   
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: none;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 170px;
  padding: 11px 10px 11px 20px;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul li ul li.active > a {
  color: #203F4F;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover:after,
#cssmenu ul li ul li.active:after {
  background: #203F4F;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul > li {
  max-height: 72px;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li:hover > ul {
  right: 100%;
  left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li a {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: height .2s;
  -moz-transition: height .2s;
  -ms-transition: height .2s;
  -o-transition: height .2s;
  transition: height .2s;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 40px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 13px;
  right: 14px;
  top: 16px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #203F4F;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 16px;
  top: 21px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active:after {
  height: 100%;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #000000;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a:after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a:after {
  background: #000000;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a:before,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a:before {
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul > li {
  max-height: 72px;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  width: auto;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
  width: 170px;
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li {
  width: 170px;
  display: block;
}
@media all and (max-width: 800px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #cssmenu > ul {
 max-height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
 -ms-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
 -o-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
 transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-right ul li a {
 text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li {
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul li a {
 text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li > a {
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li ul li a {
 width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul {
 text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
 display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul.open {
 max-height: 1000px;
 border-top: 1px solid rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.25);
  }
  #cssmenu ul {
 width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu ul > li {
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 12px 20px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul > li:after {
 display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:after,
  #cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:before,
  #cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:after,
  #cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:before {
 display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li ul,
  #cssmenu ul li ul li ul,
  #cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul li ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul li ul li ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul li ul li:hover > ul {
 left: 0;
 position: relative;
 right: auto;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li ul li,
  #cssmenu ul li:hover > ul > li {
 max-height: 999px;
 position: relative;
 background: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li ul li a {
 padding: 8px 20px 8px 35px;
 color: #ffffff;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li ul ul li a {
 padding: 8px 20px 8px 50px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > a {
 color: #000000;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button {
 display: block;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 15px 20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 14px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 color: #ffffff;
 cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:after {
 display: block;
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 height: 3px;
 width: 22px;
 border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
 right: 20px;
 top: 16px;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:before {
 display: block;
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 height: 3px;
 width: 22px;
 border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
 right: 20px;
 top: 26px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='navBar'><nav id='nav' class='wow fadeInDown animated' data-wow-delay="1s">
    
<div id='cssmenu'>
 <ul id="media">
 <li><a href='#'><span>Mystery Crocs</span></a></li>
 </ul>
<ul id="main">
 
   
   <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
   <ul>
      <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>The Classics</span></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href='#menFull'><span>Mens</span></a></li>
              <li><a href='#womenFull'><span>Womens</span></a></li>
                <li><a href='#girlsFull'><span>Girls</span></a></li>
            <li class='last'><a href='#boysFull'><span>Boys</span></a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Loafers</span></a>
           <ul>
            <li><a href='#'><span>Mens</span></a></li>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Womens</span></a></li>
                <li><a href='#'><span>Girls</span></a></li>
            <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Boys</span></a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
       <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Boots</span></a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href='#'><span>Mens</span></a></li>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Womens</span></a></li>
                <li><a href='#'><span>Girls</span></a></li>
            <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Boys</span></a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
       <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Sneakers</span></a> <ul>
            <li><a href='#'><span>Mens</span></a></li>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Womens</span></a></li>
                <li><a href='#'><span>Girls</span></a></li>
            <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Boys</span></a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
       <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Flip Flops <br>and Sandals</span></a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href='#'><span>Mens</span></a></li>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Womens</span></a></li>
                <li><a href='#'><span>Girls</span></a></li>
            <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Boys</span></a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Jibbitz</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
 </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: Post the relevant coding. Your link might break sometime in the future, and the question will lose value

Comment: Please follow the instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question. Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: I want to point on a similar problem and a solution that might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035048/navigation-bar-disappears-with-css-animations/60755398#60755398

Answer (score 0):

Well I've copied your code in this fiddle and it actually is fixed?

I didn't change anything - or did I get that wrong?

```
#navBar {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3Lst3aqg/1/

Comment: Hmm, Ok, so it works without animated.css on there, but once you add the animated.css effects it breaks :/

Comment: added animate.css and a z-index to #navBar and it works fine here:

https://jsfiddle.net/3Lst3aqg/1/

Comment: Now if you look at the one you sent the nav bar is no longer funtional

Comment: what exactly do you mean with no longer functional? the navbar is fixed and the dropdowns are working?

Comment: I figured out why it wasnt working on my end, i had the entire thing inside a div (including the nav bar) that had an animation and thats what broke it, to fix it i just took the nav out of that div and now it all works, thanks for your help!

Comment: Well now another problem arose, the things i was using for the user to press and navigate back to the top just broke